# Why am I losing photons in a window?

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, geometry

I'm trying to model a window.

[image]

For some distribution of light rays hitting the window, I'd like to determine the output angles, and the number of photons which are reflected or transmitted. I'd like to show these graphically at each stage, hence my probability treatment.

Say, you have an even distribution of photons hitting a window. The integral of this distribution is 1.

```
anglesofphotons = Table[{x, 0.6366}, {x, 0, Pi/2, 0.001}];
anglesincident = Interpolation[anglesofphotons]
ListPolarPlot[anglesofphotons];
NIntegrate[anglesincident[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}] (* 1 *)
```

I can easily determine the probability of transmission or reflection for each angle. Here my window has a refractive index of 1.5.

```
Plot[{transmissionorreflectibity[x, 1, 1.5][[1]], 
  transmissionorreflectibity[x, 1, 1.5][[2]]}, {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Probability per angle", ""}, {"Input Angle", 
    "Reflection or Transmission?"}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Reflection", "Transmission"}]
```

[image]

So, now I know the number and angle of photons which are going to be transmitted. The integral is roughly 85%, i.e. 85% of photons are transmitted.

```
photonstransmitted = 
  Table[{x, 
    transmissionorreflectibity[x, 1, 1.5][[2]]*anglesincident[x]}, {x,
     0, Pi/2, 0.01}];
ListPolarPlot[photonstransmitted];
photonstransmittedint = Interpolation[photonstransmitted];
NIntegrate[photonstransmittedint[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}];(* 0.85 *)
```

We have worked so far is in terms of the incident angles. We need to convert these angles into the new angles in the window itself relative to the bottom surface normal. I have a function which gives me the new angles.

```
Plot[newangle[x, {0, 1}, 1, 1.5], {x, 0, Pi/2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Input Angle", "Output Angle"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So, now we can convert the light rays that have been transmitted to these new angles.

```
windowdistribution = 
  Table[{newangle[x, {0, 1}, 1, 1.5] - Pi, 
    photonstransmittedint[x]}, {x, 0, Pi/2, 0.001}];
ListPolarPlot[windowdistribution]
windowdistributionint = Interpolation[windowdistribution];
NIntegrate[
 windowdistributionint[x], {x, 0, Max[windowdistribution[[;; , 1]]]}] (*  43 % *)
```

But! Horror!!! Now, my integral of the photons is no longer 85%, but 43%. I shouldn't have lost half the photons just by the new angle of the rays in the window!!!

I don't understand how to correct for this. Is it my mistake?

I can force the integral area to be 85%, by applying a multiplier, but that suggests that some angles have an occupation of greater than 100%.

I don't see an obvious jacobian to apply either. I'm pretty stuck.

I can do raytracing to solve the problem, but I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to do it analytically using the approach here. I'm obviously missing something...

This details the problem well, I think:

```
ListPolarPlot[{anglesofphotons, photonstransmitted, 
  windowdistribution}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.7}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Probability", ""}, {"Probability", 
    "What happens to the photons?"}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Incident Photons", 
   "Incident Photons which will be transmitted", 
   "Transmitted Photons, angle with respect to bottom surface"}]
```

[image]

---

Functions:

```
transmissionorreflectibity[thetai_, n1_, n2_] := 
 Block[{rs, rp, ts, tp, transmission, reflectivity, result, 
   reflectionprob, transmissionprob, costhetat, sin2theta},
  
  (* into the window , check if above critical angle*) 
  If[n1 > n2 && thetai > ArcSin[n2/n1], 
   reflectionprob = 1.; 
   transmissionprob = 1 - reflectionprob;
   (*result = RandomChoice[{reflectionprob, 
   transmissionprob}\[Rule] {{"reflection"}, {"transmission"}}];*)
   
   Return[{reflectionprob, transmissionprob}]; 
   ]; 
  
  (* otherwise *) 
  sin2theta = (n1/n2)^(2) (1 - Cos[thetai]^(2));
  costhetat = (1 - sin2theta)^(1/2);
  rs = N[((n1*Cos[thetai] - n2*costhetat)/(n1*Cos[thetai] + 
         n2*costhetat))^2];
  rp = N[((n2*Cos[thetai] - n1*costhetat)/(n2*Cos[thetai] + 
         n1*costhetat))^2];
  reflectionprob = (rs + rp)/2; 
  transmissionprob = 1. - reflectionprob;
  (*result = RandomChoice[{reflectionprob, 
  transmissionprob}\[Rule] {{"reflection"}, {"transmission"}}];*)
  
  Return[{reflectionprob, transmissionprob}]; 
  ]


(* if transmitted, what is new angle (with respect to the normal)  *) 

directedangle[a_, b_] := 
 If[Sign@Det[{a, b}] >= 0, VectorAngle[a, b], 
  2 \[Pi] - VectorAngle[a, b]]

newangle[angle_, normal_, n1_, n2_] := 
 Module[{costheta, newangle, reflection, sin2theta, refraction, 
   angle2, direction},
  direction = Normalize
    [{Sin[angle], -Cos[angle]}];
  costheta = -(Dot[ direction, normal]);
  sin2theta = (n1/n2)^(2)*(1 - (costheta^2));
  reflection  = direction - 2 (direction.normal)*normal;
  
  If[sin2theta > 1, 
   Return["TIR"]
   ];
  
  refraction = (n1/n2)*
     direction + ((n1/n2)*costheta - Sqrt[1 - sin2theta])*normal; 
  refraction = Normalize[refraction];
  newangle = directedangle[normal, refraction];
  Return[newangle];
  ]
```

Comment: At first sight, I would say you have a little problem with the underlying mathematics ... Firstly, you seem to confuse the terms "probability" with "probability density function". And secondly, take a look at how the distribution of transformed random variable is correctly calculated ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377041/change-of-variable-in-a-probability-distribution) or google something in line with "distribution change of variables").

Comment: I suspect you are right!!! Let me go away and google!...and fall into a deep hole! (joking...only a little bit)

Comment: Okay, I dug the hole. Now I'm stuck. 

Say that I'm using $f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\left|\frac{d}{d y}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\right|$ to change between angles. 

`array = Table[{x, newangle[x, {0, 1}, 1, 1.5] - Pi}, {x, 0, 0.7, 
    0.001}];
int = Interpolation[array, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
array2 = array;
array2[[;; , 1]] = array[[;; , 2]];
array2[[;; , 2]] = array[[;; , 1]];
inv = Interpolation[array2];
Plot[inv[int[x]], {x, 0, 1}]; (* is a true inverse*) 

Plot[photonstransmittedint[inv[x]]*Abs[inv'[x]], {x, 0, 0.7}] (* is complete nonsense? *)`

Comment: Actually, this is correct. After applying this transformation, the integrals match (both 85%). However, I need to understand why it is okay for a probability density (if I understand correctly) to be greater than one.

Comment: why is your starting distribution (``anglesofphotons``) being constant with the value $2/\pi\approx 0.6366$? Because $\int_0^{\pi/2} p(\phi)\, \mathrm d \phi$ has to be $1$, of course. What if the initial angle spans only from $0$ to $\pi/5$? Then the distribution will have values $5/\pi \approx 1.6>1$. Is that still weird to you? :-)

Comment: Nope! And I did a lot more reading on PDFs, no need to be <1 at all. Thanks for your help! - I think this solves all the problems using the conversion of coordinates.